# tin can API or xAPI send statement to the LRS

Tags: javascript, json, tin-can-api

I am using tin can api or xAPI  and I tried this javascript code to send a JSON statement to the LRS and it's worked correctly but I have a problem I need to send specific record like the URL that opened in the window browser or any record but it couldn't send so any help

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    $(".clickme").click(function(){
        var url = window.URL;
        var tincan = new TinCan ({
            recordStores: [{
                endpoint: "https://cloud.scorm.com/tc/HD1A9O7JK5/",
                username: "naaj11@hotmail.com",
                password: "******* my Pass",
                allowFail: false
            }]
        });

        tincan.sendStatement({
            actor: {
                mbox: "mailto:your.email.address@example.com"
            },
            verb: {
                id: "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/attempted"
            },
            target: {
                id: "http://tincanapi.com/activities/sending-my-new-statement"    
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Comment: This won't fix your code, but you should fix your code so that it's always aligned on the left to improve readability. This seems like it's aligned on the right in some parts, left in others, and anchored to the left at the end.

Comment: You appear to be using the legacy coding style with TinCanJS. I would suggest switching to the newly recommended approach of interacting with the `TinCan.LRS` object directly, making the calls asynchronous, and doing proper error handling. There is an example demonstrating current suggested best practice on the home page at http://rusticisoftware.github.io/TinCanJS/ . With that in place we need to know what the error status code and/or message from the library/LRS is for why it failed to record the statement.